# Can dynamic SVG images have right click functionality in the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, snap.svg

I'm working on a project where I am generating an SVG image (using snap.svg) inside of a div. I am wanting to know if there is a way to make it so that users can right click on the SVG and use "copy image" to copy it to the clipboard like any other image. Thanks.

Edit:

I think I could create an img and set the source to a serialized string of the SVG, but I'm worried that wouldn't be very optimal as the SVG is changing constantly from user input. Is there something obvious that I am missing?

Edit 2:

I can successfuly create an img copy of the SVG that allows me to have the right click functionality. However, my previous concern still stands as I would have to serialize the SVG and generate a new img each time a change is made.

Comment: do some research first, provide more details and show us what youd did

Comment: Add event listener for click on the SVG, check it’s a right click, and if so update the img?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a "download image" or something similar button next to the svg, which could download the svg when its needed.

Comment: How does adding a button with label "Download image" automatically download the image for you?

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is actually something that I've done already, but I wanted the added functionality of being able to copy/paste as well. To do the download button, I created an anchor element when the button is clicked, set its href attribute to the SVG's xml, then executed the .click() through code.